# SPFx: which QueryTemplate can I use in pnp.sp.search?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

I wonder which QueryTemplate available to use with `pnp.sp.search`?

For right now I find only one property :"(IsDocument:True)"

```
 pnp.sp.search({
                Querytext: query,
                RowLimit: 20,
                StartRow: 0,
                SelectProperties: ["Title", "Author", "Path", "FileType", "RefinersTextListOWSTEXT"],
                QueryTemplate: "(IsDocument: True)"
            })
```

Comment: Hi @Ann, does my below answer help you in any way?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap is it work like "Author" - name of contentipe, 'johndoe' - value

Comment: If you want to add query based on content type, you can use it like: `{searchTerms} contenttype:picture`

Comment: @GaneshSanap "Author" and contenttype is a managed properties?

Comment: Yes, those are managed properties in SharePoint.

Comment: List of all standard properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `QueryTemplate` is a string that contains the text that replaces the query text, as part of a query transform.

**Source**: [QueryTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview#querytemplate)

It allows other properties as well like:

```
{
  '__metadata': {
      'type': 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest'
   },
  'Querytext': 'sharepoint',
  'QueryTemplate': '{searchterms} Author:johndoe'
}
```

You can also use query variable like `{User.Name}`, `{Site.URL}`, etc. Check list of query variables at:

1. [Understanding query transforms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/understanding-query-transforms-b31631a5-0c1f-436e-8061-fd807bb96ae1)
2. [Query variables in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/query-variables)

---

**Update from comments**:

You can find list of all standard properties at: [Overview of crawled and managed properties in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview) - few properties might not be available in SharePoint online

Comment: It must be wright a little bit different `QueryTemplate:"(Title='test')"`